# OWL: How to refer to property holder's properties?

Tags: owl

This is a question about OWL (Web Ontology Language). There might be some mistakes of terms as I am a very beginner.

I want to represent a painting activity as a **Painting** class.

- **Painting** has a property **TargetSurface** whose range is a **Surface** class:

  - **Surface** has properties **SurfaceColor** (range: **Color**), etc.
- **Painting** has a property **TargetColor** whose range is a **Color** class.

Now I want to represent the objective of painting as a property of **Painting**.  It would be something like: a property **Painting.Objective** has a range that is an instance of **Change** class (let's say, **Change1**), which involves properties **Change1.What** = **TargetSurface.SurfaceColor** and **Change1.ToWhat** = **TargetColor**.

My question is that **Objective** is referring to properties of **Painting** (**Painting** is a holder of **Objective**; referred properties are **Painting.TargetSurface.SurfaceColor** and **Painting.TargetColor**).  How can we represent this in OWL?  An ugly solution would be representing the properties of **Change1** as xsd:string; **Change1.What** = "parent.TargetSurface.SurfaceColor" and **Change1.ToWhat** = "parent.TargetColor".  Are there better solutions?

Note that **Painting.TargetSurface** and **Painting.TargetColor** will be referred to in other properties of **Painting**.  So making an instance **Change2** which directly refers to **Painting.TargetSurface.SurfaceColor** and **Painting.TargetColor** would not be a good idea.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with "punning" in OWL2. Punning takes advantage of the fact that properties are objects too. We do something similar when modeling property attributes. We can use the property in the subject position of a triple when specifying the domain attribute, e.g. `TargetSurface rdfs:range Surface`. You can similarly specify `rdf:Property` in the object position of the `rdfs:range` assertion for your `What` property. An example assertion could be `Change1 What TargetColor` where `Change1` is your individual change of the painting, `What` is the property and `TargetColor` is the property that is changed (which is used here as the object of the triple).

Comment: Thanks for telling me "punning". However I think it is not perfect. `Change1 What TargetColor` specifies `Change1.What` is a `TargetColor`, but it does not mean this `TargetColor` is a property of a class that has `Change1` as an `Objective` property. Right?

Comment: You need to be clear about distinguishing instances/individuals from properties. The naming convention dictates beginning with an uppercase letter for individuals & classes and lowercase for properties. Using this naming convention, I restate my prior example as `Change1 what targetColor`. `Change1` is an individual of class `Change`. `what` is a property with domain `Change` and range `rdf:Property`. `targetColor` is the your property with domain `Painting` and range `TargetSurface`. The assertion indicates `Change1` is referring to a change of the painting's target surface's color.

Answer (score 0):

From the answer of @Jess, a solution came up to my mind.

We prepare two general classes. `Holder` class (properties `Context`, `HeldVia`) refers to a class that holds a class `Context` as a property `HeldVia`. `Ref` class (properties `A`, `B`) refers to a class that is held by `A` as a property `B` (i.e. like an `A.B` operator).

Then we can represent `Painting.Objective` as follows. An informative representation would be:

```
Painting.Objective = Change1
Change1.What = Ref(Ref(Holder(Change1,Objective),TargetSurface),SurfaceColor)
Change1.ToWhat = Ref(Holder(Change1,Objective),TargetColor)
```

Note that `Holder(Change1,Objective)` refers to `Painting` since `Painting` is holding `Change1` as an `Objective` property.

More formally, the above would be represented as:

```
Painting.Objective = Change1
Holder1.Context = Change1
Holder1.HeldVia = Objective
Ref1.A = Holder1
Ref1.B = TargetSurface
Ref2.A = Ref1
Ref2.B = SurfaceColor
Ref3.A = Holder1
Ref3.B = TargetColor
Change1.What = Ref2
Change1.ToWhat = Ref3
```